# Zombie when calling completion block in background thread

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, nszombie

I pass a completion block to my method, this completion block will be called in the background when a network request is finished. Unfortunately, if the calling object is deallocated in the meantime, the app crashes:

ViewController (which may be deallocated because it's popped from the navigation stack) code:

```
__unsafe_unretained ViewController *weakSelf = self;

[[URLRequester instance] sendUrl:url successBlock:^(id JSON) {
    [weakSelf webserviceCallReturned:JSON];
}];
```

URLRequester-Code (made simpler, of course):

```
- (void)sendUrl:(NSString *)urlAfterHost successBlock:(void (^)(id))successBlock {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        sleep(2);
        successBlock(nil);
        return;
    });
}
```

If, in this 2 seconds, the ViewController gets popped from the navigation stack, the app crashes. What am I missing?

Comment: unfortunately, weakself is set nevertheless

Comment: You could change the __unsafe__unretained to __weak.  From what I have read __weak takes care of released objects whereas __unsafe__unretained does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `__unsafe_unretained`, then the reference remains around even after the object is deallocated. So if the view controller gets popped, then `weakSelf` is now pointing to a deallocated object.

If you change it to `__weak` instead, then when the view controller gets deallocated, it will set `weakSelf` to `nil`, and you'll be fine. You don't even need to do a check for if `weakSelf` is set to anything, because calling a method on `nil` has no effect.

Comment: Your advice is good in that it should fix the problem, but I disagree slightly.  Please see my response.

Comment: And I disagree with your answer, because it should remain weak, since in the case that the view controller has already been popped, you don't want to start executing methods on it that might cause problems, since it's no longer a part of the view hierarchy.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the "problems" you're concerned about?  I can't think of one that wouldn't also be a problem when the vc is on top of the navigation stack.  Anyway, please note the test in my answer which doesn't rely on the reader's knowledge of weakly qualified properties.

Comment: Let's just say, either is a valid solution. And yes, your check would prevent possible issues if the view controller had already been popped. Although making it weak prevents us from hanging onto something that otherwise should be deallocated from memory immediately, so it's more memory friendly to make it weak, especially if the request hangs for a while. And if the user's internet connection was malfunctioning, and they repeatedly went into this view controller and back, they could stack up lots of instances that wouldn't deallocate until the requests timed out.

Answer (score 2):

It seems quite a few people think that 'self' inside a block must always be a weak (or unretained) copy.  That's usually not the case**.

In this situation the misunderstanding is causing the crash, by leaving a zombie around.  The right thing to do is to refer directly to self in the block (not unsafe_unretained, not weak), just like you'd like normal code to look.  The effect will be that the block will retain the instance pointed to by 'self' -- the view controller in this case -- and it won't be destroyed until the block is destroyed (presumably by the url requester).

Will it be damaging to the view controller to process the result of the web request even though it has been popped?  Almost certainly not, but if you think it will be, check for that condition in the block.

```
if (![self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:self])
    // I must have been popped, ignore the web request result

   // Re the discussion in comments, I think a good coder should have misgivings about
   // this condition.  If you think you need it, ask yourself "why did I design
   // my object so that it does something wrong based on whether some other object
   // (a navigation vc in this case) contains it?"

   // In that sense, the deliberate use of weakSelf is even worse, IMO, because
   // it lets the coder ignore _and_obscure_ an important question.
else {
    // do whatever i do when the web request completes
}
```

**The need for weak or unretained pointers in blocks stems from the fact that blocks will retain the objects they refer to.  If one of those objects directly or indirectly retains the block, then you get a cycle (A retains B which retains A) and a leak.   This can happen with any object to which the block refers, not just 'self'.

But in your case (as in many) the view controller referred to by self does not retain the block.

Comment: great explanation, thanks! But wouldn't `weak` be better in this case, as the `webserviceCallReturned:` method wasn't called then (isn't necessary if the VC is popped).

Comment: That's an interesting question.  As the other answer points out, weak declaration will have a desirable effect.  But I think this ought to be thought of as a side-effect.  I think I'd prefer code simplicity (no extra qualifiers) and code clarity (an explicit condition in the block if you need it) over the cute (too cute for my taste) side-effect of weak.

Comment: I agree that weak is better here. I know it's not always necessary, but if it's been popped and otherwise should be deallocated, it shouldn't do anything here. To try to do something when it's already been popped could actually cause issues in some cases, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

The good practice in using block (especially delayed ones) is to make a local copy of the block in the calling method. In your case it should be done in -(void)sendUrl:successBlock:

```
successBlockCopy = [successBlock copy];
```

and then call

```
successBlockCopy(nil);
```

It should retain your viewController for a while until completion.

Also it is better to use __weak instead __unsafe_unretained to avoid problems with suddenly released objects.

Comment: This is unnecessary actually, because the block being run by dispatch_async will capture the successBlock, which will make a copy of it. So it doesn't need to be copied again, it's just redundant.